# Spaces in middle of each row in file csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

I have a problem with me file csv. It's saving with spaces in middle of each row. I don't know why. How do I solve this problem? I'm asking because I don't find any answer and solutions to this.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import random

def dict_ID_aeropuertos():
  with open('AeropuertosArg.csv') as archivo_csv:
    leer = csv.reader(archivo_csv)
    dic_ID = {}
    for linea in leer:
      dic_ID.setdefault(linea[0],linea[1])
  archivo_csv.close()
  return dic_ID

def ruteoAleatorio():
  dic_ID = dict_ID_aeropuertos()
  lista_ID = list(dic_ID.keys())
  cont = 0
  lista_rutas = []
  while (cont < 50):
    r1 = random.choice(lista_ID)
    r2 = random.choice(lista_ID)
    if (r1 != r2):
      t = (r1,r2)
      if (t not in lista_rutas):
        lista_rutas.append(t)
        cont += 1

  with open('rutasAeropuertos.csv', 'w') as archivo_rutas:
    escribir = csv.writer(archivo_rutas)
    escribir.writerows(lista_rutas)

  archivo_rutas.close()

ruteoAleatorio()
```

Here is the file csv AeropuertosArg.cvs:

```
1,Aeroparque Jorge Newbery,Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires,Ciudad Autonoma de Buenos Aires,-34.55803,-58.417009
2,Aeropuerto Internacional Ministro Pistarini,Ezeiza,Buenos Aires,-34.815004,-58.5348284
3,Aeropuerto Internacional Ingeniero Ambrosio Taravella,Cordoba,Cordoba,-31.315437,-64.21232
4,Aeropuerto Internacional Gobernador Francisco Gabrielli,Ciudad de Mendoza,Mendoza,-32.827864,-68.79849
5,Aeropuerto Internacional Teniente Luis Candelaria,San Carlos de Bariloche,Rio Negro,-41.146714,-71.16203
6,Aeropuerto Internacional de Salta Martin Miguel de Guemes,Ciudad de Salta,Salta,-24.84423,-65.478412
7,Aeropuerto Internacional de Puerto Iguazu,Puerto Iguazu,Misiones,-25.731778,-54.476181
8,Aeropuerto Internacional Presidente Peron,Ciudad de Neuquen,Neuquen,-38.952137,-68.140484
9,Aeropuerto Internacional Malvinas Argentinas,Ushuaia,Tierra del Fuego,-54.842237,-68.309701
10,Aeropuerto Internacional Rosario Islas Malvinas,Rosario,Santa Fe,-32.916887,-60.780391
11,Aeropuerto Internacional Comandante Armando Tola,El Calafate,Santa Cruz,-50.283977,-72.053641
12,Aeropuerto Internacional General Enrique Mosconi,Comodoro Rivadavia,Chubut,-45.789435,-67.467498
13,Aeropuerto Internacional Teniente General Benjamin Matienzo,San Miguel de Tucuman,Tucuman,-26.835888,-65.108361
14,Aeropuerto Comandante Espora,Bahia Blanca,Buenos Aires,-38.716152,-62.164955
15,Aeropuerto Almirante Marcos A. Zar,Trelew,Chubut,-43.209957,-65.273405
16,Aeropuerto Internacional de Resistencia,Resistencia,Chaco,-27.444926,-59.048739
17,Aeropuerto Internacional Astor Piazolla,Mar del Plata,Buenos Aires,-37.933205,-57.581518
18,Aeropuerto Internacional Gobernador Horacio Guzman,San Salvador de Jujuy,Jujuy,-24.385987,-65.093755
19,Aeropuerto Internacional Piloto Civil Norberto Fernandez,Rio Gallegos,Santa Cruz,-51.611788,-69.306315
20,Aeropuerto Domingo Faustino Sarmiento,San Juan,San Juan,-31.571814,-68.422568
```

Comment: Can you add a few lines of the content of `AeropuertosArg.csv` to the question?

Comment: @DavisYoshida Yes of course!

Comment: this is moot: `archivo_csv.close()`  the with statement autocloses...

Comment: You may have extra spaces in the initial csv. `dic_ID.setdefault(linea[0],linea[1])` could be `dic_ID.setdefault(linea[0].strip(), linea[1].strip())`. But that's just a strange way to do `dic_ID[linea[0].strip()] = linea[1].strip()`. But you only end up using the key (row 0) so why even bother with a `dict` when a set would do?

Comment: `r1 = random.choice(lista_ID)` and `r2 = random.choice(lista_ID)` is bettter written as `r1,r2 = random.sample(lista_ID,k=2)` - and they will never be the same unless there are duplicate values inside `lista_ID` to begin with ... `sample` takes values without replacing them back into a list.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I did not know. Thank you for information.

Comment: When I run this code there are no spaces in the output.

Comment: @tdelaney Because I will need this dict later

Comment: @Davis It's strange because it keeps giving me the spaces

Comment: Which spaces? Are you talking about the internal (unescaped, unquoted) spaces in strings like 'Tierra del Fuego'? If so, you need quoting or escaping for the output. Not related to newline handling. Also, what OS are you running on?

Comment: @smci No, I was saying white spaces between rows, but the problem is already solved by Patrick Artner

Comment: Calvin: but your title and first line both say ***"spaces in middle of each row"***. Like in ''Tierra del Fuego'. This is very misleading to anyone who would read this in future, can you edit it? It should not be necessary to run the code in order to see where the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that the csv-module `writerows` has its own "newline"-logic. It interferes with the default newline behaviour of `open()`:

Fix like this:

```
with open('rutasAeropuertos.csv', 'w', newline='' ) as archivo_rutas:
#                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is also documented in the example in the documentation: [csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

> If *csvfile* is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''` [1]

with a link to a footnote telling you:

> **[1]**   If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

You are using windows which does use `\r\n` which adds another \r which leads to your "wrong" output.

---

Full code with some optimizations:

```
import csv
import random

def dict_ID_aeropuertos():
  with open('AeropuertosArg.csv') as archivo_csv:
    leer = csv.reader(archivo_csv)
    dic_ID = {}
    for linea in leer:
      dic_ID.setdefault(linea[0],linea[1]) 
  return dic_ID

def ruteoAleatorio():
  dic_ID = dict_ID_aeropuertos()
  lista_ID = list(dic_ID.keys())
  lista_rutas = set()            # a set only holds unique values 
  while (len(lista_rutas) < 50): # simply check the length of the set
    r1,r2 = random.sample(lista_ID, k=2)  # draw 2 different ones
    lista_rutas.add( (r1,r2) )            # you can not add duplicates, no need to check    
  with open('rutasAeropuertos.csv', 'w', newline='' ) as archivo_rutas:
    escribir = csv.writer(archivo_rutas)
    escribir.writerows(lista_rutas)

ruteoAleatorio()
```

Output:

```
9,3
16,10
15,6
[snipp lots of values]
13,14
13,7
20,4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I learned a lot of with your answers. Evidently this is the solutions to problem.